# Integrating WebSockets for GraphQL subscriptions in SvelteKit application with Apollo Server and Neo4j GraphQL Library

Tags: websocket, apollo-server, sveltekit, graphql-subscriptions, neo4j-graphql-js

I'm trying to integrate GraphQL subscriptions in my SvelteKit application using Apollo Server and the Neo4j GraphQL Library. I have successfully set up the basic GraphQL queries and mutations, but I'm struggling with implementing subscriptions.

Here's a simplified version of my code of my `src/routes/graphql/+server.ts` file:

```js
import neo4j from 'neo4j-driver';
import { Neo4jGraphQL } from '@neo4j/graphql';
import { ApolloServer, gql } from 'apollo-server-svelte-kit';

const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password'));

const typeDefs = gql`
  type User {
    id: ID! @id
    username: String!
    password: String! @private
    posts: [Post!]! @relationship(type: "POSTED_BY", direction: OUT)
  }

  type Post {
    id: ID! @id
    title: String!
    content: String!
    author: User! @relationship(type: "POSTED_BY", direction: IN)
  }

  type Query {
    users: [User]
    posts: [Post]
  }

  type Mutation {
    signIn(username: String!, password: String!): User
    signUp(username: String!, password: String!): User
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  // resolver logic
};

const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
  typeDefs: typeDefs,
  driver: driver,
  resolvers: resolvers
});

const server = new ApolloServer({
  schema: await neoSchema.getSchema(),
  context: ({ req }) => {
    return {
      driver: driver,
      req: req
    };
  }
});

await server.start();

export const POST = server.handleRequest;
```

I would like to know how to implement GraphQL subscriptions using Apollo Server and the Neo4j GraphQL Library in SvelteKit. Specifically, I want to be able to subscribe to real-time updates for certain queries, such as receiving new posts as they are created.

---

First, I attempted to import the `WebSocketServer` class from the `"ws"` package and the `Neo4jGraphQLSubscriptionsSingleInstancePlugin` from `@neo4j/graphql`. I added the `Neo4jGraphQLSubscriptionsSingleInstancePlugin` to the list of plugins in the `Neo4jGraphQL` constructor.

The example code provided in the Neo4j GraphQL Library documentation, which uses Express and `createServer` from the `"http"` package to create an HTTP server. Then, it initializes a `WebSocketServer` instance by passing the HTTP server object to it. This approach didn't work in SvelteKit since the HTTP server is internally handled by SvelteKit, and I couldn't properly initiate the `WebSocketServer`.

Here's an example code snippet from the documentation that uses Express:

```js
// ... previous code ...

async function main() {
    // Apollo server setup with WebSockets
    const app = express();
    const httpServer = createServer(app);
    const wsServer = new WebSocketServer({
        server: httpServer,
        path: "/graphql",
    });

    // Neo4j schema
    const schema = await neoSchema.getSchema();

    const serverCleanup = useServer(
        {
            schema,
            context: (ctx) => {
                return ctx;
            },
        },
        wsServer
    );

    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema,
        plugins: [
            ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({
                httpServer
            }),
            {
                async serverWillStart() {
                    return Promise.resolve({
                        async drainServer() {
                            await serverCleanup.dispose();
                        },
                    });
                },
            },
        ],
    });
}

main();
```

In SvelteKit, the underlying server setup and management are abstracted away, and we don't have direct access to the HTTP server object.

I was expecting to find a way to integrate the WebSocket functionality required for subscriptions within the SvelteKit framework, or an alternative approach to enable GraphQL subscriptions in my SvelteKit application using Apollo Server and the Neo4j GraphQL Library.

If anyone has successfully implemented GraphQL subscriptions in SvelteKit using Apollo Server and the Neo4j GraphQL Library or has any insights or code examples, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you!